# javascript onclick to change mp3 player

Tags: javascript, html, audio

**I have some question**:
I have a `music website` which can display the music rank and then the user can click the music to play that song with a `mp3` player like **spotify** click the song, and then the bottom player will go and play it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiWKU.jpg

But i actually can do is: **click the right side play btn**, it only play mp3 at that area, not at the website.
`so how can i do?`

this is my code:

```
<ul style="list-style: none">
  <li>Audio Files
    <ul id="list">
      <li><a href="#" data-value="http://music1.mp3">music1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-value="http://music2.mp3">music2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-value="http://music3.mp3">music3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-value="http://music4.mp3">music4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<audio id="audio" controls="controls">
  <source id="audioSource" src=""></source>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript. I have created a snippet with your code below.

Run the snippet to see each link play its music source using the `data-value` attribute.

```js
//Element is your target element where the function is being called
function play(element) {

//get player by id
  var player = document.getElementById('audio');
  //get source by id
  var source = document.getElementById('audioSource');

//set source to current data-value attribute of of element where function is being called
  source.src = element.getAttribute('data-value');

//load
  player.load();
//play  
  player.play(); 
};
```

```html
<ul style="list-style: none">
  <li>Audio Files
    <ul id="list">
      <li><a href="#" onclick="play(this)" data-value="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3">music1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="play(this)" data-value="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3">music2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="play(this)" data-value="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3">music1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<audio id="audio" controls="controls">
  <source id="audioSource" src=""></source>
</audio>
```